# Meteor - how to output checkbox value's with Meteor.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor, checkbox

I'm having a problem with outputting the value of selected checkbox's with Meteor.js. The checkbox value is outputting as [object Object] in the browser. Could someone please help me out.

**HTML**

```
    <head>
  <title>project</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{>addStatusForm}}
</body>

<template name="addStatusForm">
    <form class="addStatus">
      {{#each category}}
        <input type="checkbox" name="categoryCheckbox" class="boxCheck" value={{categoryDesc}}>{{categoryDesc}}<br>
      {{/each}}
        <input type="text" name="status">
        <input type="submit" value="Add status">
    </form>
    {{#each status}}
    <p>{{statusDesc}} {{category}}</p>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

**Helpers**

```
Template.addStatusForm.helpers({

  status: function () {
    return Status.find();
  },

  category: function(){
    return Category.find();
  }
});
```

**Events**

```
Status = new Mongo.Collection('status');
Category = new Mongo.Collection('category');


Template.addStatusForm.events({

  'submit .addStatus': function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var statusInput = event.target.status.value;

    var categorySelected = $('.boxCheck:checked').val();

    //var categorySelected = event.target.categoryCheckbox.value; tried this
    //var categorySelectedString = JSON.stringify(categorySelected); tried this also

    //console.log(categorySelected); just testing console output
    //console.log(statusInput); just testing console output

    Status.insert({
        statusDesc : statusInput,
        category : categorySelected
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem with this is not how it is stored (`console.log(typeof categorySelected )` shows that it is a string and not an object) it is that you are defining the 'category' field twice within this template when displaying the data, once from a helper and once as a field inside of the collection object. It gives the helper priority over the collection data so you get the object being returned from `return Category.find();` which is an object and hence the [object Object] output

Two quick solutions here:

A) Change the name of the `category` helper to `categories` or something else

B) (Possibly more meteoric) move the code inside your each into a status template giving it a bit of isolation so it can't see the parent templates category field

```
{{#each status}}
  <p>{{statusDesc}} {{category}}</p>
{{/each}}

/*...BECOMES...*/

{{#each status}}
  {{>statusTemplate}}
{{/each}}


<template name="statusTemplate">
  <p>{{statusDesc}} {{category}}</p>
</template>
```